# There is something wrong with Sony QX1？

Tags: camera, sony

I'm a user of the product Sony QX1 and recently there is something wrong.

As known, there are two ways to set up connection between the camera and another device. The camera could set up a wifi connection like a hotspot, to which the other device could connect. And this just works pretty smoothly.

The problem lies in the other mode when the camera and a PC or cellphone connect to the same wifi. According to the statements described in Camera Remote API, the function setCameraFunction is supposed to help reach and control the camera remotely and it has two values, "Remote Shooting" and "Content Transfer".

When using the "Content Transfer" mode, there appears an unknown error described as "Not Available Now".

The overall result is as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Length: 40
Content-Type: application/json

{"id":1,"error":[1,"Not Available Now"]}
```

Comment: Did you ever get this to work @ZhangMinghe? I am having the exact some problem, talking to the Sony Camera through my router, not using the Sony Wifi AP. I am able to Start and Stop recording but having no luck with content transfer

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on an interface to the QX1.

I've run into the "not available now" error for the first time today and put it down to overwhelming the camera with requests.

To fix it, I waited a couple of minutes to see if it would clear itself (it didn't). Then I tried a power down and immediate (in human time) power up (didn't fix it).

I then performed a Shutdown in which I removed and wiped the memory card (although I am not sure the memory wipe was a key part of the fix, it may have just been a sufficiently long time to clear all the capacitors/memory in the camera).

I'll post again if I notice any patterns or more elegant fixes.

Answer (score 0):

The Camera Remote API is only officially supported via a direct WiFi connection.  While you can use it over a router, the functionality is not tested or guaranteed.

Comment: Exactly. But in practice, as I had tried many times, it works pretty well except that one problem. Is there a way to inform the developer so that they could improve it?

Answer (score 0):

Please use `getAvailableAppList`, this mode may give you all available APIs. You need set essential flag before use main functions.

In my case, `setCameraFunction` is not available just after Wi-Fi connection.
To use this function, `startRecMode` is required.

Comment: I'm working on a a7R, and I needed to startRecMode before anything else would work

Comment: I am using RX0 and it doesnt have startRecMode